# Is there anything wrong with this HTML using the sup tag and CSS?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, vertical-alignment, superscript

I'm having trouble with this HTML in IE8 CO at a customer site, but not on my XP IE8 VM.  However, I have managed to reproduce the problem in IETester and have tracked it down to a `vertical-align: middle` style being applied to an element that contains a `<sup />` tag.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <span style="vertical-align: middle;"><sup>test</sup></span>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The above HTML example is the smallest possible example I can create that breaks in IETester and on the customer site.  However, it works fine in my XP VM that has IE8 on it, so it may work fine for you, too.  We need the `X-UA-Compatible` `IE=edge` meta tag for our main site, so I've included it here.

The symptoms of the break is that IE renders a blank white page and seems to be caught in an infinite operation - if left long enough, IETester crashes out (although I haven't confirmed with the customer that the same thing happens at their site with real IE).

It took me a long time to track this down to the `<sup />` tag, and then the CSS applied to its parent element (which happened to be a `<label />` tag in our actual website, but it seems it behaves the same way with `<span />` tags, too).

**Is there anything wrong with this HTML / CSS, or is it just IE8 being funny?**

In my tests, I've tried IE6, IE7, IE9, Chrome, FireFox, Opera and Safari and none of them exhibit the same behaviour as the specific version of IE running at the customer site.

Comment: IE Tester is not very reliable IMO.

Comment: @ScottSimpson thanks for your feedback.  However, IETester is the only utility I've found that reproduces the issue I have at the customer site.  My own IE8 on my XP VM doesn't reproduce it.

Also, thanks for replacing the image.  When I tried it (using the "code" feature), it just seemed to render it as HTML :)

Comment: Does the HTML validate? Are you getting any JS errors? Maybe see which service pack your customer has on XP? (Just trying to help brainstorm).

Comment: Thanks for the advice.   I've just updated the HTML in the original post with XHTML that validates against the W3C validator (can't believe I didn't think to check this anyway!).  The same issue is present with this "valid" HTML, so I guess I can close this question.  I checked the customer IE version number, but didn't check their version of XP Service Pack - either way, it looks like the HTML is valid, meaning my question is invalid.  Thanks again.